# Collision with babylon.js

Tags: javascript, collision, babylonjs

I'm trying to manage collision with babylon.js. Everything runs well with an automatic move, but with keyboard event, when the ball moves, it loses collision it's property.

You can take a [look here](http://www.babylonjs-playground.com/#LKCKO#24). I've tried to move the ball with `sphere.moveWithCollisions();` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey this is because collisions are about player moving (like in FPS) and you are using physics simulation. 
To manually update an physic object, just call .updatePhysicsBodyPosition() after updating it